# Hide or Unhide icons in Autodesk Forge Viewer Toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I would like to hide or unhide icons and commands on the toolbar. I find out the easiest way to do this is: add the following line or lines to your *.css file.

.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-modelStructureTool{display:none!important} made the model browser button and so on and so forth. But... I found no commandline to hide the following icons?: How can I hide this last 3 icons...?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUeVc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already answered here : [How to remove toolbar buttons in Autodesk Forge Viewer version 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218779/how-to-remove-toolbar-buttons-in-autodesk-forge-viewer-version-7)

To complete Bryan's answer with the buttons you want to hide, here's a few more `class` names you can use :

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-modelStructureTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-explodeTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-measurementSubmenuTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-orbitTools{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-panTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-zoomTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-bimWalkTool{display:none!important}
.adsk-viewing-viewer #toolbar-cameraSubmenuTool{display:none!important}
```

Using your browser inspector you can easily find these `class` names in the **html** .